# admob close button on mraid expanded panel

Tags: admob

Admob SDK 6.2.1 comes with a default panel close button for Mraid ad when expanded. May I know whether it is possible to disable it and let the creative handle the panel close button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AdMob [MRAID docs](http://media.admob.com/mraid/v1/docs/index.html), you can call `mraid.useCustomClose(true)` to remove the AdMob custom close button. Just make sure your creative handles closing appropriately so the user doesn't get stuck on the ad.

Comment: TEMP NOTE: Support for this feature hasn't actually been pushed yet, it should go out hopefully today, or later this week. I'll add another comment once it's pushed.

Comment: The new JavaScript is now live, and useCustomClose is now supported.

Comment: Does anyone know if this behavior has changed? It's working fine for me on iOS, but on Android the default close button won't go away (even though `mraid.getExpandProperties().useCustomClose` is `true`).